# Translate HtmlString into HtmlTextWriter

Tags: c#

I am trying to write and send an e-mail using a form to construct the body.  The form has an editor (Kendo Editor) which returns Html rather than pure string.

An HtmlTextWriter builds the e-mail body inserting information from the database.  When it comes to adding the body (say in the the signature block) the submitted text through the editor comes out as string with all the Html tags included.

Say if you wrote:

"Something

Something else..."

If I use Server.Decode I will get this:

```
<p>Something</p><p>Something else...</p>
```

If not I get something like this:

&lt;p&gt;Something,&lt;&lt;p&gt;Something else..,&lt;

All I want to happen is that I get what's typed in on the editor.

```
            string salution = "Dear";
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);

            string text = Server.HtmlDecode(email.Body);//Not doing what's required

            html.WriteEncodedText(String.Format("{0} {1},", salution, name));
            html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.P);
            html.WriteEncodedText(text);
            html.RenderEndTag();

            html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);
            //Method to generate a list
            BuildCertList(html, missingDocs);
            html.RenderEndTag();

            html.Flush();

            string htmlString = writer.ToString();

            //Then send the email....using htmlString as the body
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to decode the HTML body and then encoding it again three lines later?

Comment: How do I add it without encoding it again is basically my question.  There doesn't seem to be a method to add already encoded strings??